# How to bulk upload a site template (solution) to multiple site collections

Tags: site-template, solution-deployment, bulk

We've multiple site collections with customized site templates (or solutions).
Is it possible to change all the solution (in all the site collections) at once when the template has been updated?

Platform is SharePoint Online (2013) with Office365